# Append all files in a given directory to one file

Tags: file, bash, shell, command-line

I have a directory full of small text files. 
I want to create a new text file which has contents of all the small files (first have to convert the contents to lower case). Once, I have appended the small text files to get the larger one, I just want to sort it and only save unique elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat directoryname/*|tr [:upper:] [:lower:] >filename.txt
sort -u filename.txt
```

or just:

```
cat directoryname/*|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]|sort -u > unique_elements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: i missed the part about the lowercase, see Kimvais' answer for the case transforming.

---

First, to append all the contents of files in `/path/to/dir` to 1 file:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec cat {} >> /var/tmp/large_file \;
```

Or:

```
cat /path/to/dir/*.log >> /var/tmp/fie_with_all_files_contents
```

Then to sort and only keep unique items:

```
sort -u /var/tmp/large_file -o /var/tmp/large_file
```

Or, with redirection:

```
sort -u /var/tmp/large_file > /var/tmp/sorted_file
```

[man sort](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/sort/)
[man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)